# DetailList selecting first item on load

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have a [Detaillist](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist) implemented which loads 1000 items. How do I make the first item to be selected after loading?

Answer (score 0):

You call `this._selection.setKeySelected("KEY_VALUE_OF_FIRST_ITEM", true, true)`

[Selection component Doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/selection)